# How to change the file type wording to distinguish different types of images

Tags: nautilus, files, 17.04

I found that working with images on Ubuntu is quite a hassle as all image files is of type "Image". Is there a way to change the wording to say "Image" and "RAW Image"?

For instance my camera produces both raw and jpeg files, and I would like to separate them by type in an ascending order. Another possibility would be to order by name, but the "order by name" doesn't include the file ending, so that is also useless to separate file types.

Picture examples:
[Screenshot #1 - folder containing raw and jpeg files ordered type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh6DN.png)
[Screenshot #2 - Folder containing raw and jpeg files ordered by name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB0DL.png)

**Is there a way to change this behavior?** Or does anyone have another solution to this problem?

Comment: Try to add the `MIME Type` in Visible Columns.